# How to write summation of squared divergence terms in index summation notation?

Tags: index-notation

Sorry if this has already been asked before, but it's really difficult to try and explain the problem in words.

Anyways, I want to express the following:

$$\phi = \left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)^2$$

My first instinct would be to square the divergence of $u_i$, but this would result in:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}+ \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)^2$$

I've narrowed it down to either of the following, but they both seem more like "hacks" than correct. I've also included the general line of thinking behind the ideas as well.

### Idea 1:

$$ \text{Idea 1: }\quad \frac{\partial (u_k)^2}{\partial (x_k)^2}=\frac{\partial (u_1)^2}{\partial (x_1)^2} + \frac{\partial (u_2)^2}{\partial (x_2)^2} + \frac{\partial (u_3)^2}{\partial (x_3)^2} = \left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)^2 $$

This being analogous to:

$$ \text{Inspiration for Idea 1:} \quad \frac{(A)^2}{(B)^2} = \left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^2$$

### Idea 2:

$$ \text{Idea 2: } \quad \frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3} = \left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)^2 $$

This idea was inspired from the incompressible form of the shear stress equations for fluids:

$$ \text{Inspiration for Idea 2:} \quad \frac{\partial^2 \tau_{ij}}{\partial x_j \partial x_j} = \frac{\partial^2 \tau_{i1}}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \tau_{i2}}{\partial x_2^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \tau_{i3}}{\partial x_3^2}$$

---

On a slightly related note, if anyone knows of a good resource that goes over common index summation notation forms of common math expressions or the "rules" of index summation notation, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a "correct" way of doing it.

Using the Kronecker delta, $\delta_{ij}$:

$$   \delta_{ij} =\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & i\not=j \\
      1 & i=j \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

Using that, we can get:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)^2 = \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_k} \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_k} \delta_{jk} $$

This way, we use don't repeat indices more than twice and ensure that the two pair of indices are the same (and so square themselves).